# Find the minimum value of a group of columns based on the value of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

This is for SQL Server. Is there a way to get the minimum value of only a select group of columns based on the value of another column? In this example, I want to find the minimum transaction that each Name had and place that in the 'Minimum Transaction' column. I cannot hard code the value of 'Name'. I have tried a subquery, but I can't wrap my head around how the logic would work.

```
SELECT ID, Name, Transactions, Minimum Transaction =
   (
   SELECT MIN(Transactions) 
   FROM MyTable M
   JOIN MyTable M ON N.ID = M.ID
   )
FROM MyTable N
WHERE Name = 'Sarah' OR 'Sue' OR 'Joe' OR 'Tim'
```

**Expected Outcome**

| ID | Name | Transactions | Minimum Transaction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sarah | $5 | $1 |
| 2 | Sarah | $1 | $1 |
| 3 | Sue | $10 | $4 |
| 4 | Sue | $4 | $4 |
| 5 | Sue | $6 | $4 |
| 6 | Joe | $4 | $4 |
| 7 | Tim | $12 | $12 |
| 8 | Tim | $14 | $12 |

Comment: Use a windowed `MIN`. See the documentation's [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/min-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-the-over-clause).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MIN(Transactions) OVER(PARTITION BY Name)` :

```
SELECT ID, Name, Transactions, 
MIN(transactions) over (partition by Name) as "Minimum Transaction" from 
MyTable
order by id;
```

`PARTITION BY` as opposed to `GROUP BY` only affects the window function and doesn't affect the returned rows.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efab2fb143aad044254ce8eeacc86c61)

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: You don't need a subquery/derived table or a join for that, also I think you meant `WHERE Name IN ('Sarah', 'Sue', 'Joe', 'Tim')`. The query in your fiddle is correct

Comment: @Charlieface you're right, I didn't read OP's code honestly, I thought he used some joins to get (id, name transactions) so I only added the relevant part to it. Fixed my answer, thank you!